# Application throws InputMismatchException when string is assigned to double

Tags: java, string, inputmismatchexception

I am writing a program where I need to check if a string (`name`) contains any whitespaces or not.

Here's part of my program :

```java
    public static void main()
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in) ;
        String name = "" ;
        boolean error = false ;
        do {
            if(error) System.out.println("Sorry, error. Try again") ;
            error = false ;
            
            System.out.print("Enter your name : ") ;
            name = sc.next() ;
            if(name=="") error = true ;
        } while(error) ;
        
        double amount = 0.00 ;
        do {
            if(error) System.out.println("Sorry, error. Try again") ;
            error = false ;
            
            System.out.print("Enter amount of purchase : ") ;
            amount = sc.nextDouble() ;
            if(amount<=1) error = true ;
        } while(error) ;
    }
}
```

For checking errors in the `name` string input, I need to check if the string contains any whitespaces or not because otherwise `java.lang.InputMismatchException` is thrown when it accepts `amount` (and when the entered `name` contains whitespace with another string).

Is there any predefined function that does this?

Comment: Aside from main question, compiler informs about problems via *errors* and/or *warnings*. The *exceptions* are thrown at *runtime*. But to run java code first it needs to compile without errors.

Comment: @Pshemo yea it compiles without errors the question was about adding a condition for the error

Comment: during runtime input

Comment: Sorry - mixed you up with OP. I'll delete, but think it really better here as it addresses the orig question and effects that were misleading the OP. Here is that comment: Super Coder, note I have deleted my comments. It is practicably impossible with your code (which should be corrected in the question for the equals stuff) to enter a name with whitespace, even with quoting (the reason why I deleted my comments). We are getting too academic about this question, and you should probably be doing nextLine, not next(). There's no reason why the user should not be able to enter a name with a space

Comment: @g00se yea I figured that out about an hour after I wrote the program lol I thought someone would just figure that out using logic but first answer I got was about the q that I asked :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following method to determine if a `String` contains a white-space character.

```java
boolean containsSpace(String string) {
    for (char character : string.toCharArray()) {
        switch (character) {
            case ' ', '\t', '\n', '\r', '\f' -> {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Also, you're going to want to test the `name` value using the `String.equals` method, as opposed to the `==` equality operator.

```java
if (name.equals("")) error = true;
```

Furthermore, the `main` method requires a single `String` array, or `String` varargs parameter, to be valid.

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
```

Here is a quick demonstration of how I would implement the task.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    String name;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Name: ");
        name = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!containsSpace(name))
            break;
        System.out.println("Name contains white-space.  Re-enter.");
    }
    
    double amount;
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Amount: ");
        try {
            amount = Double.parseDouble(scanner.nextLine());
            break;
        } catch (NumberFormatException exception) {
            System.out.println("Invalid amount.  Re-enter.");
        }
    }
    
    System.out.printf("Name is '%s'%n", name);
    System.out.printf("Amount is %,f%n", amount);
}
```

Comment: so there isn't any predefined functions ?

Comment: @g00se, you're right, actually, I was trying to avoid recommending a `Pattern`.  Thanks for the correction, I overlooked it.

Comment: Yes, you can use `String.matches`, which requires a regular expression, the pattern `\s` will match any white-space character.  Or, if you are looking for a single character you can use the `String.indexOf` method.  So, `name.indexOf(' ') != -1` would mean an index was found, thus it contains a space character.

Answer (score 1):

> I am writing a program where I need to check if a string (name) contains any whitespaces or not.
> so there isn't any predefined functions?

Of course, there is - isWhitespace,
plus the trim() method might be considered,
to remove leading and trailing spaces from the user input: name = scanner.next().trim();

```
boolean containsSpace(String string) {
  for (char character : string.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(character)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

And the second part of your problem - to get the "amount" as a double,
I would split into two simplistic functions to follow single responsibility principle and improve maintainability and testability.
And I will put method getDouble(String string) into a dedicated class, and package, let say: myproject.common.Numbers

So the whole program will consist methods like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  final var instance = new StackOverflow();
  instance.parseNameAndAmount();
}

void parseNameAndAmount() {
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  final var name = getName(scanner);
  final var amount = getAmount(scanner);
  scanner.close();

  print("Name is %s".formatted(name));
  print("Amount is %s".formatted(amount));

}

String getName(Scanner scanner) {
  String name;
  do {
    print("Enter a name with no spaces: ");
    name = getName(scanner.nextLine().trim());
  } while (name == null);
  return name;
}

String getName(String string) {
  if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
    return null;
  }

  if (containsSpace(string)) {
    return null;
  }
  return string;
}

boolean containsSpace(String string) {
  for (char character : string.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isWhitespace(character)) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}


double getAmount(Scanner scanner) {
  Double amount;
  do {
    print("Enter amount of purchase (valid number): ");
    amount = getDouble(scanner.nextLine().trim());
  } while (amount == null);
  return amount;
}

Double getDouble(String string) {
  if (string == null) {
    return null;
  }

  try {
    return Double.valueOf(string);
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    return null;
  }
}

void print(String string) {
  System.out.println(string);
}
```

As I mentioned testability and maintainability,
one of the tests might look like this, of course to be thorough,
more tests needs to be done.

```
@Test
void getDouble_When_NegativeWithExponent() {
  // Given
  final var given = "-12.45E9";

  // when
  final var actual = stackOverflow.getDouble(given);

  // Then
  assertThat(actual)
      .isNotNull()
      .isNegative();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read a floating point number you have to explicitly ask for it using Scanner.nextDouble(). next() returns a String. You can not assign a string to a number in Java.

Comment: yea I know I am just looking for a way to report an error in case there is a whitespace